# Docker - how to setup connection to container to localhost

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker on my OS X.

Currently i'm connecting to my container at ip.address.received.from.docker:8080 using:

```
docker run  -d -p 8080:80 -p 2022:22
```

how can I set localhost:8080 to forward to ip.address.received.from.docker:8080 so i could use localhost instead of the ip address?

Comment: The tutorial explains this. Basically you use nginx for that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy .

Comment: Using a front end server to agregate different service under one adress is the pro way ;)

Comment: By the way, the answer that you just accepted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385476/6309 would work here too.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

How to bind a dockerized service to a local socket?

---

#### Solution

According to the documentation, the format of `--publish` option is: `ip:hostPort:containerPort  |  ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort`.
Hence, if you want to bind to localhost you could use `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080` and you're done.

**This was tested with this command: `docker run -p 127.1.2.3:9080:9080 --rm -it debian` running a `netcat` listening on the port 9080.**

---

#### Bonus

Btw, I guess that you run `sshd` in your container according to the option `-p 2022:22`. I would like to point [this article made by a Docker engineer that worth the reading](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/).

Have fun!

Comment: this didn't work on OS X... any idea why? I did -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Any error message? Any log? Anything that would help you (and I) to have an idea on why it didn't work. Are you using a VM?

Comment: I'm using Docker with an Ubuntu + Apache container. When browsing to 127.0.0.1:8080 using Safari, I receive: Safari can't open the page because Safari can't connect to the server 127.0.0.1

Comment: Show your `docker run` command please, what is the output of `nc 127.0.0.1 8080` when your container is running?

Comment: `docker run  -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 -p 127.0.0.1:2022:22 -v /Users/asafnevo/Sites:/var/www -it --name="pico" pico_server`

Comment: It does not output "nothing". Actually, **once a successful connection**, it waits for input from `stdin`. Try the same `nc` command when the container is not running and you will get an error message (`nc: unable to connect to address 127.1.2.3, service 9080`). In other words this "nothing" means that you can connect to your Apache service from within the container. Using `docker exec` from the same container try to [`wget` (or `curl`)](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) the default web page served by Apache.

Comment: It actually outputs the same nothing.. What got me thinking.. maybe the localhost:8080 port is taken? I will try a random port to see

Comment: well even when trying the random ports 9080 and 9999 it does the same behaviour

Comment: What about  `wget` or `curl` ?

Comment: apache is live an running on the container.. if i'm running the same run command with `-p 8080:80`, then browsing to the docker-machine ip on port 8080 brings me to the apache server in the container

Comment: Btw, maybe it make sense just to forward the localhost to the ip with the port from OS X instead from Docker ? just to set that localhost:8080 will forward to my.ip.address:8080 (which set to forward to the container 80 port)