# Docker for Windows: Using localhost

Tags: nginx, docker, ip, localhost, virtual-machine

I am running docker toolbox on windows 7. I have 3 containers, `nginx`, `php`, `mysql`. I understand that docker is running a virtual machine and that to access my site I need to use the virtual machine ip rather than `localhost`.

So my site is at `192.168.99.100`. I need to access my site via a domain name like so: `mysite.com`.

The closest I have coming to figuring this out is this: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15740

But it still doesn't really solve the issue. In my Windows `hosts` file I have tried:

`127.0.0.1 localhost mysite.com`
and
`192.168.99.100 mysite.com`

And still I get `site can't be reached` error when I try and load `mysite.com`. If I use `192.168.99.100` the site loads.

How can I fix this, or is it even possible with a virtual machine?

Comment: Did you port forward your published port? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385476/6309)